# Does Python Eric manage virtualenv?

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, ide, virtualenv, eric-ide

I'm a bit of a newbie programmer and I've done most of my programming up to this point in notepad++. Right now I'm just storing all my python 3 virtual environments (venv) in different directories and loading them manually before executing my code.

> IE: Load my python virtualenv in a terminal on one screen, open my
>   notepad++ on another screen. Edit, save, then executing the new script
>   in the terminal.

This method seems to work okay for the most part, but it seems very manual and some of my directory structures have become rather complex.
I'm trying to find a good IDE that supports/manages venv for different projects so I can easily load-up, track, and manage dependencies. I have been looking at Eclipse and Eric, but I cannot tell if either of them will accomplish this (or if it's just inherent that any IDE will do this, and they both will).

TL;DR
Will an IDE like Eric or Eclipse also manage my python virtual environments? Or do I need a different application for managing these?

Comment: take a look at pycharm. It will manage the environments and much much more.

Comment: Thanks Brewmaster - pycharm does look like it will do everything I'm looking for.